# Is there a way to have multiple file uploads turn into multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have a model called Photo and obviously I don't want to upload one photo at a time, so I replaced the new photo form with multi-file uploading. I am not quite sure how I can make these file uploads turn into unique photo models.

```
<%= bootstrap_form_with(:model => photo, :local => true) do |form| %>
    <%= form.file_field :image, :multiple => true, :direct_upload => true %>
    <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Edit: I am using Active Storage on Rails 6.0.0 rc2

Comment: what are the parameter passing when you submit the form??? check in your server log

Comment: Yes, there is definitely a way. At least one way, I would say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that come across this problem, here was my solution:

```rb
  def create
      photo_params[:images].each do |image|
        @photo = current_user.photos.build
        @photo.image = image
        @photo.save
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't make multiple photo models. You probally mean multiple records. A model is a blueprint of the table in your database.

Check your terminal logs when you submit the form and you will probally see that in the params you will have something like: photo => [ files here ]

So in your controller create you have to loop through the array and create a photo record for each photo, something like this:

```rb
def create
  params[:photo].each do |photo|
  Photo.create(file: photo.file)
end
```